# Should I significantly edit my own question or should I ask a new one?

Tags: discussion

Last month I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585747/a-property-of-the-focus-of-the-cissoid-of-diocles) about a property of the curve known as the *cissoid of Diocles*. It hasn't received any answer nor comment.

Upon reflecting on the problem once more, I've recognized that the question can be restated in a much simpler way, so that it only asks about a property of any *parabola* (which is undoubtedly a curve that a lot more users are familiar with).

So, what I'm asking is:

> Should I edit my question so that it becomes about a parabola (significantly reducing or even removing altogether the part about the cissoid) or should I ask a new question instead?
>
> If asking a new question is more appropriate, should I write an answer to my initial question pointing to the new one or what else?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the existing question is good, and should be left as is.  If the answer to the new question leads to an answer to the old question, you can add an answer to the old question at that time, pointing to the new question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will do just that.